# Cant use brackets in javascript under CMS Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms, cms-block, bug

```
let legValue = parseInt(legLenght.value);
        let currHeight = e.value;
        let numHeight = parseInt(currHeight.substring(0,3));
        let optionsFound;

        if(legValue ==64){
            optionsFound=[43, 44, 45];
        }
```

I have the code above, when i execute it under catalog -> content-> CMS block, i get this weird bug when i look at it in developers tool in chrome

[image]

the brackets seem to disappear in the code... how may i fix this

Comment: optionsFound string or array? if you are using string, put double quotes optionsFound="[43,44,45]", if its array, optionsFound = ["42","43"]

Comment: its an array which contains number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define code like this

```
let optionsFound = [];

if(legValue == 64){
   optionsFound.push(43,44,45);
}
```

Comment: also i made let optionsFound= new Array();  using [ ] doesnt work..... but with combibnig two now it works thanks ........